# Request a root shell when app starts

Tags: android, root

I want to write a Android app for rooted phones that behaves in the following way:

I want to have a root shell at my disposal to which I can issue commands. So what I want is for my app to request a root shell at startup, and then:
1)If it obtains the shell (user grants superuser permissions) the app should continue
2)If it does NOT obtain it (user denies permissions or superuser request popup times out) the app should terminate immediately

Now, reading another question here on SO I found out that you can request a root shell by using:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
```

However, this returns immediately, whether you have gained permission or not. You can issue:

```
p.waitFor();
```

But this will never return if the user actually has given permission, it will only return if permission is denied.

I want a reliable way to get a su shell and keep it, and know if I actually got the permission or not. Any ideas?

Comment: your process p **is** your root shell, so it's actually a good thing it doesn't end immediatly.

Comment: Yes, but that's my point: how do I wait for the user to either grant or deny root access and reliably check if I actually got root access or not? When the first instruction I posted above executes the program execution continues immediately regardless of whether I got permission or not, doesn't even wait for the permission request popup to disappear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can call `exitValue()`.

It will throw an exception if the process is still running, and probably 1 (not 0, at least) if the permission was denied (as the command will have failed).

```
int result = 0;
try {
    result = p.exitValue();
} catch (IllegalThreadStateException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
if (result == 0) {
    // Your process p is root and running
} else {
    // su failed
}
```

It is possible that you have to wait for the permission request popup to disappear first. In this case, there may be something to try with the input/output stream availability.

Comment: Thanks, however I understand that with this solution I'd have to wait "manually" for enough time for the request popup to timeout to be sure I actually god the permission, even if the permission is given immediately... correct? Is there no way to just wait the correct amount of time (ie: until either permission is denied/granted OR popup times out) ?

Comment: i don't know (as i have not tested the authorization part). I figure you can always assume it worked, send your commands to your root shell, and have another thread wait for the result of the su command.